# "Empfehlungen" vs "testimonial"

Tags: difference, german-to-english

When a client gave us content from their German website, they seemed to use the word "Empfehlungen" as the label on a tab for the page that features testimonials. Is that correct? I ask because when I brought this up to one friend from Germany, he gave me this link to Wikipedia which shows that the word "testimonial" is actually used and understood in Germany.

[image: testimonials- on wikipedia]

What would be a comparison between the two words and when to use either one?

Comment: I would find "Empfehlungen" weird because it can also mean "recommendations" and at least in my mind that meaning is way more present.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The English term *"testimonial"* seems to have been adapted by advertising agencies who are known to use English technical terms whenever possible.

This is not the case for average non-advertising people who likely never heard about a *"testimonial"* before.

So despite having a German Wikipedia page it is not a common or known term outside the advertising industry.

Possible translations for *"testimonial"* depend on context and include:

> Zeugnis, Empfehlungsschreiben, Attest, Referenz, Erfahrungsbericht

On a webpage - depending on branch - we use

> **Referenzen**, Referenzprojekte, Referenzobjekte, Kundenmeinung

Answer (score 2):

Die wörtliche Übersetzung für "Empfehlungen" in Englisch lautet "recommendations".

Als "testimonial" kann man zum Beispiel eine prominente Persönlichkeit ansehen, die irgendein Produkt in einem Werbespot empfiehlt:

> Als Testimonial steht das Top-Model im Mittelpunkt der Medienkampagne.

Comment: Wenn man "testimonials" übersetzen möchte / muss, wird meist "mit (besten) Empfehlungen (von)" verwendet, das allerdings auch nur im Kontext von Stellenausschreibungen od. Bewerbungen.